# google analytics Same web property ID is tracked twice

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website that have articles. An article can be publish by any department. An article have the department name and sometimes a subject (education, hobby, ...). I want to track the articles for each department and also the subject. A subject can be found in any department. So i created two tracking ID.
In my main index that list all the articles from all departments i have :

```
ga('create', 'UA-12345-1', 'auto');  //main website tracker ID for all articles
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

In the page of the articles with subject *hobby* to track the page view, i have :

```
ga('create', 'UA-12345-14', 'auto', {'name': 'hobby'});    //subject tracking ID    
ga('hobby.send', 'pageview', { 
        'page': url_partial_path, 
        'title': 'hobby'    
        });
```

In the finance department index page to track the page view of the index, i have :

```
ga('create', 'UA-12345-14', 'auto', {'name': 'FinanceDept'});
ga('FinanceDept.send', 'pageview');
```

I know i am doing something wrong since i get the error `Same web property ID is tracked twice` but also because when i check the real time update in GA i can see that some articles are tracked twice. Under active page i have the same url twice with different title (double tracking!).

**Active Page**       **Page Title**      **Active Users**

```
blog/test   test1      20  56%
blog/test   hobby      5    8%
```

I though having different title was the right way of doing it. How can i track one article twice (from the department point of view and from the type point of view) without doubling my numbers?

Can it be done?
I also read somewhere that i can use the views as filter? how do you do that since GA can't access my code?

Comment: This looks fine, as long as you aren't include both the `FinanceDept` and `hobby` trackers on the same pages. Are you sure you're not including both at the same time or typo'd one of the other property IDs?

Comment: Why don't you use custom dimensions? One for department name and another for subject. That avoids your awkward use of multiple named trackers and different property IDs.